# Why can't I use command \i on psql? It says no such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, windows, errors, psql, command-line

I am trying to use command \i 'C:\Users\Public\person.sql'; on windows on psql.
And it says C:UsersPublicperson.sql: No such file or directory
Although file does exist. I tried to relocate file on different locations by I get the same answer. Is there any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: Clearly you need to escape backslashes.

Comment: The error message indicates why it didn't work.  Notice the lack of backslashes?  Your backslashes got eaten by psql, consumed in protecting characters that didn't need to be protected, and not passed on to the filename.

Answer (score 2):

Use forward slashes:

```
\i c:/Users/Public/person.sql
```